# How to display flatlist's selected item from one screen to another screen in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

### How to display flatlist's selected item from one screen to another screen in react-native ?

I am trying to select gender using flatlist .so when i select gender from flatlist at that time i want to show that selected gender value on next screen in react-native.so please help me .Thank you in advance.

How i can achieve this functionality.

Comment: So upto now can you get the selected value to state ?

Comment: yes i got it. But now i want to show that selected value on next screen. @AkilaDevinda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario, you can simply pass the values using params in react-navigation - [View](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html)

Assuming that you can get flat list selected value ( Gender ) clearly :)

Assuming that you have to pass values to **SecondScreen**

*This is function that get's selected item from FlatList*

```
itemOnClickListner = gender => {
  // gender is the selected gender of the user

  //Now you need to pass it to second screen
  this.props.navigation.navigate('SecondScreen', {
    screen: SecondScreen,
    Gender: gender,
  });

};
```

Inside SecondScreen ( The screen we are passing values ) state you need to save the passing value like this

```
  this.state = {
      SelectedGender: this.props.navigation.state.params.Gender,
    };
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this solution. @Akila Devinda

Comment: Sure.. If your problem solved then mark this as a correct answer :) If you have any issues post here :)

Comment: Please can you show this in functional component where this.state is not used?